# factory pattern example singleton issues?

Tags: c++, factory

I set out to create a factory pattern example.  My goal was that I would not have to change the factory code. As I added new derived classes they would automatically work in the factory.  Here is what I came up with for a registration system.  It uses a singleton factory.
Are their downfalls of using a singleton factory?
I plan on using this in some RPC server code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

namespace configNM{

class config{
   public:

     config(const std::string & filename);
     config(){};

     std::string getConfFileName()const{return _confFilename;};
   private:
      std::string _confFilename;
   protected:

};

class configColumnHeaders:public config{
   private:
   static bool registered;
   configColumnHeaders(){};
   configColumnHeaders(const std::string & filename):config(filename){std::cout << "configColumnHeaders" << std::endl;};


   protected:

   public:
   static std::unique_ptr<config> create(std::string in){
      std::cout << "creating configColumnHeaders" << std::endl;
      std::unique_ptr<configColumnHeaders> MyPtr(new configColumnHeaders(in));
      return std::move(MyPtr);
   };
};

class configColumnsNoHeaders:public config{
   private:

   configColumnsNoHeaders(){};
   configColumnsNoHeaders(const std::string & filename):config(filename){std::cout << "configColumnsNoHeaders" << std::endl;};
   static bool registered;
   protected:

   public:

   static std::unique_ptr<config> create(std::string in){
      std::unique_ptr<configColumnsNoHeaders> MyPtr(new configColumnsNoHeaders(in));
      return std::move(MyPtr);
   };

};

class configFixed:public config{
   private:
   configFixed(){};
   configFixed(const std::string & filename):config(filename){std::cout << "configFixed" << std::endl;};
   static bool registered;
   protected:
   static std::unique_ptr<config> create(std::string in){
      std::unique_ptr<configFixed> MyPtr(new configFixed(in));
      return std::move(MyPtr);
   };

   public:
};

class configFactory{
public:
  typedef std::unique_ptr<config> (*configCreateFunction)(std::string);
  std::map<std::string,configCreateFunction> registeredConfigs;

  static configFactory* instance(){
          static configFactory factory;
         return &factory;
      }

  bool registerConfig(const std::string & name,std::unique_ptr<config> (createFunction)(std::string)){
   registeredConfigs.insert(std::make_pair(name,createFunction));
   return true;
  }
  std::unique_ptr<config> createConfig(const std::string& name, std::string filename)
  {
      return registeredConfigs[name](filename);
  }


};

}

using namespace configNM;
config::config(const std::string & filename){
   _confFilename=filename;
}

bool configColumnHeaders::registered = configFactory::instance()->registerConfig("column_headers", configColumnHeaders::create);
bool configColumnsNoHeaders::registered = configFactory::instance()->registerConfig("columns_no_headers", configColumnsNoHeaders::create);
bool configFixed::registered = configFactory::instance()->registerConfig("fixed", configFixed::create);


int main(void){
   config myConfig("columnHeaders.json");

   auto myPtr = configFactory::instance()->createConfig("column_headers","parameter");
   auto myPtr2 = configFactory::instance()->createConfig("columns_no_headers","parameter");
   auto myPtr3 = configFactory::instance()->createConfig("fixed","parameter");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is a question for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not for SO, isn't it?

Comment: thanks.  I was not aware of code review.

Comment: Question is not really related to Thrift at all (except that you plan to use it). Took the freedom to edit that away.